# How to bulk edit image URLs in featured product images, menu custom links and in product descriptions?

Tags: wordpress, url

As per subject title, how to bulk edit image URLs in featured product images, menu custom links and in product descriptions? And in the plugin like gravity form.

I tried looking for plugins but I can't find one that update image URLs in the locations I want. Thanks